# Is there a Possibility of connecting Azure PostGreSQL Database to Powerbi?

Tags: azure, powerbi

Hi Is it possible to connect Azure Postgres SQL Database to PowerBI using Direct Query, I cant seem to find information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-data-sources) are the only data sources supported by DirectQuery:

- Amazon Redshift
- Azure HDInsight Spark (Beta)
- Azure SQL Database
- Azure SQL Data Warehouse
- Google BigQuery (Beta)
- IBM DB2 database
- IBM Netezza (Beta)
- Impala (version 2.x)
- Oracle Database (version 12 and above)
- SAP Business Warehouse Application Server
- SAP Business Warehouse Message Server (Beta)
- SAP HANA
- Snowflake
- Spark (Beta) (version 0.9 and above)
- SQL Server
- Teradata Database
- Vertica (Beta)

PostgreSQL is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources), but only in import mode. So no, you can't use DirectQuery with PostgreSQL (unless you write [your own custom connector](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/master/docs/m-extensions.md)). You can [vote](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19065214-postgresql-direct-query) for this idea though.

Comment: Azure PostgreSQL is not supported for Direct Query?

Comment: As visible from the list of supported data sources above - no, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Custom Connector that will work for Direct Query from PostgreSQL through an ODBC driver. Working on a full write-up (this month when I get time) but until then I can just share the repo here:

[DirectQuery for Postgres via ODBC](https://github.com/sgoley/DirectQuery-for-ODBC-in-PowerBI)

This is working for us to DirectQuery our Postgres data source via an Azure hosted Windows instance running the custom connector on a On-Premise gateway 24/7.